# Limpiar LineEdits y Labels al cerrar ventana secundaria Pyside

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, interfaz-gráfica, pyside

tengo un programa con interface hecha con Pyside. Es muy simple y consiste en 2 ventanas, la principal (1ª) y una secundaria (2ª) con un monton de lines edits y labels para rellenar. 
Lo que me gustaría saber es si hay una forma para que al cerrar la ventana 2ª se borren todos los campos y al abrirlo de nuevo estén todos los campos vacíos.

Puede valer limpiar al cerrar o al abrir de nuevo.

Sé que se puede hacer poniendo una a una todos los lines edits y labels en blanco al iniciarse, pero era por si hay una forma más automática y rápida.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: podrias colocar el codigo de la ventana que tienen los QLineEdit

Comment: ¿Quieres limpiar todos los QLineEdit y QLabel?

Comment: Si, quiero limpiar todo. Ahora mismo lo hago lineEdit a lineEdit y label a label con "self.lineEdit.clear()". La duda es, si hay un forma de hacer "clear" a todos los LineEdits y Labels que haya en una ventana.

Comment: Muestra el codigo de la ventana que tiene los QLineEdits y QLabels

Answer (score 0):

Los widgets que se muestran en la ventana son hijos de la ventana, o hijos de sus hijos, aprovechando esa propiedad podemos encontrarlos a todos a traves del metodo [`findChildren()`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QObject.findChildren), le debemos pasar como parámetro el nombre de la clase del widget.

Ejemplo:

```
import random
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)

        l = [QLineEdit, QLabel]

        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(3):
                w = random.choice(l)("sometext")
                grid.addWidget(w, i, j)

        clearBtn = QPushButton("Clear")
        grid.addWidget(clearBtn, 5, 0, 3, 3)
        clearBtn.clicked.connect(self.clearAll)

    def clearAll(self):
        for le in self.findChildren(QLineEdit):
            le.clear()
        for lbl in self.findChildren(QLabel):
            lbl.setText("")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```